# Obscure anime movie or series

Tags: story-identification, anime

I have looked for years (close to 11 years) for this movie I used to rent as a kid but I was so young that I do not remember the title only the plot (sot of). It is about a ship full of humans that crash landed on an alien planet inhabited by robots. The robots are actually aliens whose mind was transferred to the machines after a terrible event, that I don't remember, forced them to put their bodies on stasis. They are divided in 2 factions, the good aliens who team up with some of the humans who I believe were a family and the evil aliens who team up with the rest who of curse were evil. I think they do this because with a pilot they have access to more weapons or something like that.

The only thing I have been able to find is an image of the robots in a fanmade comic about the *Powerpuff Girls* about 5 or 6 years ago but even reverse search doesn't yield anything. And even the fan page of the comic only calls them "some robots". To make matters worse, I live in Mexico and the movie was dubbed in Spanish so I don't even know if it came out in English which has the largest number of dubs and subs.

[image]

Comment: This sounds vaguely like GoBots Battle for Gobotron, except that it is the robots that land on Earth instead of the other way around. The rest match though. With the robots as aliens transferred into robot bodies after a catastrophe and a family, that is first seen in a spaceship, helping the good robots against the evil ones.

Comment: I heard that before and I checked, it is not GoBots, definitely different kind of robots, the one on the picture are the same style if not the exact same, but thanks

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I think the movie is [Robotix](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Robotix). It was a 1985 animated series based on the Milton Bradley toy of the same name.

[image: Robotix movie cover]

From wikipedia

> Pursued by a battle cruiser, the starship of captain Exeter Galaxon crashes on the ruined planet of Skalorr and its occupants left for dead. However, the crew survives, only to immediately find themselves caught up in a battle between two factions of gigantic robot creatures - the Protectons and Terrakors - that emerge from the ground. While the Terrakors flee the scene, the Protectons befriend Galaxon and his crew, and help them rebuild their ship. During the repairs, Nara and Zarru discover that humans can interface with Robotix to enhance their abilities, while a renewed attack by the Terrakors forces Bront to put the new discovery to the test.

I found it because i figured a robot like that was based of some toy, and that its most distinguished feature was its long neck, i therefor googled `toy robot long neck cartoon` and that got the result.

Comment: I remember those toys. One of my classmates had them and we built all kinds of stuff. One of the neat things about it was that most sets came with motors, so you could actually create vehicles that you could control. It was surprisingly difficult to create things that didn't take themselves apart. :-)

Comment: you truly have no idea how happy this makes me, I am afraid of watching it because my expectations are sky high, from the bottom of my heart thank you very much, you are the best